# Youtube Data API issue with inconsistent permissions

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am having an issue accessing a list of my subscriptions. When I use the "Try this method" interface on [youtube developer docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list), it provides the following endpoint and I get a status 200....cool

1. *GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&access_token=$accessToken&key=$key*

returns

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#SubscriptionListResponse",
  "etag": "rC3zjdhEVLnLK1PkNUMeuSezIqs",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 285,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [....
```

2. When I use this same url WITH all parameters added in Postman or in my Next.js app, I keep getting:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Insufficient Permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "service": "youtube.googleapis.com",
                    "method": "youtube.api.v3.V3DataSubscriptionService.List"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

3. In the **https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials**:

[image]

4. I have my email added as a Test User.
5. I have these scopes added:

[image]

Can anybody help out here?